# Make all elements of a html class react on a click, which would modify the element itself

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a tutorial for my students, in the form of a webpage with hidden "spoilers" that the student can unhide, presumably after thinking about the answer. So, long story short, the behavior I am looking for is:

- in the beginning, the text appears with a lot of hidden words;
- when a piece of text is clicked, it appears, and stays uncovered afterwards;
- this should work with minimal overhead (not forcing me to install a complex framework) and on all my students' machines, even if the browser is outdated, even if jquery is not installed.

I searched for off the shelf solutions, but all those I checked were either too complicated or not doing exactly what I wanted. So I decided to do my own.
What I have so far is this:

```
<HTML>
<STYLE>
span.spoil {background-color: black;}
span.spoiled {background-color: white;}
</STYLE>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>SPOIL</TITLE>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <!--LINK rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".css"-->
</HEAD>
<BODY>

This is a text with <span class="spoil" onclick="showspoil(this)">spoil data</span>.
<br>
<span class="spoil" onclick="showspoil(this)">Unspoil me.</span>
<br>
<span class="spoil" onclick="showspoil(this)">And me.</span>



<script>
function showspoil(e) {
        e.className="spoiled";
}

// var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("spoil");
// for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
//        classname[i].addEventListener('click', showspoil(WHATEXACTLY?), false);
//        }
</script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

It does the job, except that I find it annoying to have to write explicitly the "onclick..." for each element. So I tried adding an event listener to each member of the class, by imitating similar resources found on the web: unfortunately, this part (the commented code above) does not work. In particular, I do not see which parameter I should pass to the function to transmit "the element itself".

Can anyone help? If I may play it lazy, I am more looking for an answer to this specific query than for pointers to a series of courses I should take: I admit it, I have not been doing html for a loooooong time, and I am sure I would need a lot of readings to be efficient again: simply, I do not have the time for the moment, and I do not really need it: I just need to solve this issue to set up a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is you are calling the method and assigning what it returns to be bound as the event listener

```
classname[i].addEventListener('click', showspoil(WHATEXACTLY?), false);
```

You can either use a closure or call the element directly.

```
classname[i].addEventListener('click', function () { showspoil(this); }, false);
```

or

```
classname[i].addEventListener('click', showspoil, false);
```

If you call it directly, you would need to change the function to

```
function showspoil(e) {
    this.className="spoiled";
}
```

Another option would be to not bind click on every element, just use event delegation.

```js
function showspoil(e) {
    e.className="spoiled";
}

document.addEventListener("click", function (e) { //list for clcik on body
    var clicked = e.target;  //get what was clicked on
    if (e.target.classList.contains("spoil")) {  //see if it is an element with the class
        e.target.classList.add("spoiled");  //if it is, add new class
    }
});
```

```css
.spoil { color: red }
.spoiled { color: green }
```

```html
This is a text with <span class="spoil">spoil data</span>.
<br>
<span class="spoil">Unspoil me.</span>
<br>
<span class="spoil">And me.</span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice solution and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function unspoil() {
  this.className = "spoiled"; // "this" is the clicked object
}
window.onload = function() {
  var spoilers = document.querySelectorAll(".spoil"); // get all with class spoil
  for (var i = 0; i < spoilers.length; i++) {
    spoilers[i].onclick = unspoil;
  }
}
```

```css
span.spoil {
  background-color: black;
}

span.spoiled {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
This is a text with <span class="spoil">spoil data</span>.
<br>
<span class="spoil">Unspoil me.</span>
<br>
<span class="spoil">And me.</span>
```

Comment: I am always totally amazed by the speed at which you can get an answer, and the willingness to help of the community !
Thanks a lot (and thanks to espacarello too) : works perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

An additional approach could be to add the click-listener to the document and evaluate the event target:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if (e.target.className == "spoil"){
       e.target.className = "spoiled";
    }
});
```

That way

- you only need one event listener in the whole page
- you can also append other elements dynamically with that class without the need for a new event handler

This should work, because the event's target is always the actual element being clicked. If you have sub-elements in your "spoil" items, you may need to traverse up the parent chain. But anyway I think this is the least resource-wasting way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var spoilers = document.getElementsByClassName('spoil');

for(i=0;i<spoilers.length;i++){
  spoilers[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    this.className = "spoiled";
  });
}
```